# Android - Unparseable date at offset

Tags: android, date-format, parseexception

i was trying to parse string date to Date, it shows unparseable date at offset. Here is my code.

```
String s= "2014-07-17 10:12:00";

SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");

Date current = new Date();

Date givenDate = sdfDate.parse(s);
```

Comment: why Z? You don't have time zone in your date.

Comment: You mean you get an exception? **ALWAYS** include the logcat in your question if you get exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

As @blackbelt suggested,You don't have time zone in your date.So change

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
```

to

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: I'm checking null condition on String date since getting same error.